# Amphp Artax bug

Tags: php, amphp

i used following very basic example of amphp/artax

$URL can be any url e.g. http://www.yahoo.com

```
$promises[$URI] = Amp\call(function () use ($client, $URI) {
                // "yield" inside a coroutine awaits the resolution of the promise
                // returned from Client::request(). The generator is then continued.
                $response = yield $client->request($URI);

                // Same for the body here. Yielding an Amp\ByteStream\Message
                // buffers the entire message.
                $body = yield $response->getStatus();

                return $body;
            });

        $responses = Amp\Promise\wait(Amp\Promise\all($promises));
```

and getting following error

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Amp\Socket\CryptoException: Crypto negotiation failed: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1414D172:SSL routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong signature type in /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/socket/src/Internal/functions.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/Loop/NativeDriver.php(172): Amp\Socket\Internal\{closure}('am', Resource id #293, Object(Amp\Deferred))
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/Loop/NativeDriver.php(68): Amp\Loop\NativeDriver->selectStreams(Array, Array, 4.782)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/Loop/Driver.php(130): Amp\Loop\NativeDriver->dispatch(true)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/Loop/Driver.php(70): Amp\Loop\Driver->tick()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/Loop.php(76): Amp\Loop\Driver->run()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/amp/lib/functions.php(158): Amp\Loop::run(Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/html/parseradvance.php(77): Amp\Promise\wait(Object(Amp\Internal\PrivatePromise))
#7 {main}
  t in /var/www/html/vendor/amphp/socket/src/Internal/functions.php on line 118
```

can anybody help me out the issue I had already set cainfo=curl.pem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a server configured with weak ciphers, which Artax rejects by default. Weaker ciphers can be allowed by passing a custom `ClientTlsContext` instance to the client on creation and setting [`withSecurityLevel(1)`](https://github.com/amphp/socket/blob/4f2927a9538a1da16d5bc99ce7a7eec6e857ec9b/src/ClientTlsContext.php#L256-L283), which defaults to `2`. See also https://github.com/amphp/artax/issues/174.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this happens because you use `http:` instead of `https:`.